# Sound cloud Integration in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have developed a music app.I want to add sound cloud integration in my app. When I login on cloud window and click on connect button i get the line below in my console.

```
-[NXOAuth2PostBodyStream open] Stream has been reopened after close
```

Please let us know about sound cloud integration where I have made a mistake.
thanks

Comment: Can you show your codes ?

Comment: - (void)open
{
      if ((contentStreams != nil) && (boundary != nil))
      {
          // If post data is to big this happens and usualy triggers an HTTP 413 error
        NSLog(@"%s Stream has been reopened after close",__FUNCTION__);
     }

    [contentStreams makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(open)];
     currentStream = nil;
    streamIndex = 0;
    if (contentStreams.count > 0)
        currentStream = [contentStreams objectAtIndex: streamIndex];
}

Comment: Application crashes after NsLog();